# Not the same object after a deserialization in a data transfer

Tags: java, serialization, drag-and-drop, jtree, data-transfer

I really need some help down here...

I'm working on drag and drop event in a `Jtree`.
I've created a `TransferHandler` to manage the drag and drop.

Source :  `KineticsTransferHandler.java`

```java
package tree;

import java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor;
import java.awt.datatransfer.Transferable;
import java.awt.datatransfer.UnsupportedFlavorException;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JTree;
import javax.swing.TransferHandler;
import javax.swing.tree.TreePath;

import datastructures.base.Acquisition;
import datastructures.base.Kinetics;
import datastructures.base.Location;

public class KineticsTransferHandler extends TransferHandler{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -5653477841078614666L;

    final public static DataFlavor ACQUISITION_NODE = new DataFlavor(Acquisition.class, "Acquisition Node");

    static DataFlavor flavors[] = { ACQUISITION_NODE };

    @Override
    public int getSourceActions(JComponent c) {
        return MOVE;
    }

    @Override
    protected Transferable createTransferable(JComponent c) {
        JTree tree = (JTree) c;
        TreePath path = tree.getSelectionPath();

        System.out.println(tree.getSelectionPath().toString());

        if (path != null) {
            Object o = path.getLastPathComponent();
            if(o instanceof Acquisition) {
                return new AcquisitionTransferable((Acquisition)o);
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void exportDone(JComponent source, Transferable data, int action) {
        if(action != NONE) {
            JTree tree = (JTree) source;
            StudyTreeModel model = (StudyTreeModel)tree.getModel();
            model.printStudy();

            tree.updateUI();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean canImport(TransferHandler.TransferSupport support) {
        boolean canImport = false;
        if (support.isDrop()) {
            Acquisition source = null;

            if (support.isDataFlavorSupported(ACQUISITION_NODE)) {
                try {
                    source = (Acquisition) support.getTransferable().getTransferData(ACQUISITION_NODE);
                } catch (UnsupportedFlavorException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                if(source != null) {
                    JTree.DropLocation dropLocation = (JTree.DropLocation)support.getDropLocation();
                    Object dest = dropLocation.getPath().getLastPathComponent();            
                    canImport = sameLocation(source, dest);
                }
            }
        }
        return canImport;
    }

    /*Verifies that the source and the dest are in the same Location*/
    private boolean sameLocation(Acquisition source, Object dest) {
        /*...
        A method to check if the source has the same Location than the dest.
        ...*/
    }

    @Override
    public boolean importData(TransferHandler.TransferSupport support) {
        boolean importData = false;
        if (canImport(support)) {
            Acquisition source = null;

            if (support.isDataFlavorSupported(ACQUISITION_NODE)) {
                try {
                    source = (Acquisition) support.getTransferable().getTransferData(ACQUISITION_NODE);
                    ((StudyTree)support.getComponent()).gettr
                } catch (UnsupportedFlavorException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    return false;
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    return false;
                }

                JTree.DropLocation dropLocation = (JTree.DropLocation)support.getDropLocation();
                Object dest = dropLocation.getPath().getLastPathComponent();

                int childIndex = dropLocation.getChildIndex();
                if (sameLocation(source, dest)) {// dest and source get the same Location
                /*...
                Management of the drop according to the dest.
                ...*/
            }
        }
        return importData;
    }

    public class AcquisitionTransferable implements Transferable {
        Acquisition acquisition;

        public AcquisitionTransferable(Acquisition s) {
            acquisition = s;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getTransferData(DataFlavor flavor)
                throws UnsupportedFlavorException {
            if (!isDataFlavorSupported(flavor))
                throw new UnsupportedFlavorException(flavor);
            return acquisition;
        }

        @Override
        public DataFlavor[] getTransferDataFlavors() {
            return flavors;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isDataFlavorSupported(DataFlavor flavor) {
            return ACQUISITION_NODE.equals(flavor);
        }
    }
}
```

It uses an `Transferable` for the data transfert that I've called `AcquisitionTransferable` (as you can see in the end).

My problem(s) came(s) from this part

Source : `KineticsTransferHandler.canImport(TransferHandler.TransferSupport)`

```java
source = (Acquisition) support.getTransferable().getTransferData(ACQUISITION_NODE);
```

The structure that I've, in the end, in `source`(the one above) is like a copy of the real one. When I'm debugging, I can see that the `source`'s ID is not the same as in the real one.

But in `support`(parameter of `KineticsTransferHandler.canImport(TransferHandler.TransferSupport)`), I've my `Jtree` which contains the structure, wich is the good one.

So, what I'm thinking is, there is a problem in the access of the structure in `getTransferData`, it may be a problem with the serialization. When I access my structure, `getTransferData` deserializes the structure and this is why I get like a clone of it.

Do you have any idea of how I should fix it?

Comment: And what what is the source's ID? What code is used to determine it?

Comment: I'm using Eclipse and when you are debugging you can see, in the Variable's widow, the id of the object. (What's it really represent and how it's defined, I'dont know.) But the thing is when I want to compare my structure and the one contained in source, I get differences...

EDIT : I've got it, misunderstanding with the term source ;)

Comment: The ID you see in the debugger could be based on the address of the object on the heap, or be some internal id used by the debugger for cross-referencing. It's not relevant.

Comment: Ok I will no more talk about ID.  
When I try to see if my source and my destination are contained in the same object, I get false... But they should be in the same structure...

Comment: I don't get it. You already have one, you are deserializing another one, and you expect them to be the same? Why?

Comment: I don't expect at all, I want it to be same. I don't have the choice (I may say, I don't know an other choice) to deserialize with this method. I need to get the drag&drop's source and I only find this method to get it, but it means my object must be serialized. I just want to know if there is an other way to get my source?

Answer (score 3):

You need to define your `DataFlavor` with a `javaJVMLocalObjectMimeType`, to signify that the transferred data resides in the local JVM. In your case, the `DataFlavor` definition should look like:

```
final public static DataFlavor ACQUISITION_NODE = 
    new DataFlavor(DataFlavor.javaJVMLocalObjectMimeType+"; class=\"" +Acquisition.class.getCanonicalName()+"\"" 
    ,"Acquisition Node");
```

Check the other two Java object MIME types [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/datatransfer/DataFlavor.html#javaSerializedObjectMimeType) also.

Comment: Thanks for that tip! A small note though - it seems that you should provide `Acquisition.class.getCanonicalName ()` instead of `Acquisition.class` there.

Comment: @MikleGarin Glad I could be of help, that one caused me a lot of headache at the time. Thanks for the correction as well, I've incorporated it into the answer.